# Development Envoirment for node-webkit

Tags: windows, linux, ide

I've been trying to get my hands dirty with node-webkit for a while, but eventually I get tired of doing everything by hand. I mean, I use Notepad++ (as good piece of software it is, it has it's limitations too) to write the code and just run nw.exe. Isn't there something out there that would allow me to code node-webkit applications, debug and run them.

I tried looking for one, but found nothing. I was suspecting that Visual Studio can be used for this, but it looks like no one had made the alterations yet. I was even considering to make my own IDE for node-webkit... using node-webkit, but it was too much hassle to do (especially without having a proper IDE in the first place).

So is there such piece of software or am I out of luck?

Edit: I'm mainly looking for an IDE for Windows, but an IDE for Linux should be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

JS and HTML aren't really good with IDEs (as seen in the apparent lack of them), honestly. It seems like you are used to Java or C# in VS where debugging is a large portion of development. With JS there isn't really a set-in-stone workflow. Get used to doing it from the console. (You might want to investigate a hot-reload configuration where the app auto-reloads when you edit the files, allowing you to fix issues really quickly)

Have you tried Sublime Text? It has project organization (so you can see all files at a glance), build routines (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to compile and run your app). That;s just scratching the surface; Sublime does a boatload more. It's built to be extensible, and thanks to Package Control allows you to install new plugins relatively easily.

-[Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

-[Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) (which you have to install after installing Sublime)

Good luck!

EDIT: There is a Jetbrains IDE (Webstorm) which you might want to check out. I have no experience with it (it's also not free or open source).

Comment: I did get used to debugging javascript from console, but so far haven't figured out how it's done with node-webkit (need to investigate more). I'm starting to believe my best bet is making a Visual Studio template (I just hope I can make VS launch nw.exe and make node-webkit dump errors, console log etc. somewhere).

Comment: You can connect to nw remotely and debug it that way: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Debugging-with-devtools#remote-debugging . You can also have it dump logs to the console with the --enable-logging flag, which is what you want (it should work with VS)

Comment: I managed to make a nw.js project template for VS. I doesn't offer any additional debug options, but manages to greatly simplify the process of managing a nw.js project, building it into a nw file and just simply running it (without having to either build it or having to copy nw.js to the project folder). As a bonus, with this template, it should be possible to code JS using TypeScript. https://github.com/jahu00/nwjsVSProjectTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to patch up a Visual Studio project template for nw.js apps. It's called nwjsVSProjectTemplate and can be found [here](https://github.com/jahu00/nwjsVSProjectTemplate).

Answer (score 0):

I started playing with node webkit lately.
Any version of jetbrains ide can debug node-webkit (I used phpStorm).

Check this for more info https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-node-webkit.html